# Reading Time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to import time series data in R with the below code. The data is from `1-7-2014` to `30-4-2017` making it 1035 data point. But when I use the below code it gives 1093 observation.

```
series <- ts(data1, start=c(2014,7,1), end=c(2017,4,30), frequency = 365)
```

Can someone help me in understanding where am I going wrong?

Comment: Read also `?ts` manual

Comment: data1 is my daily data of 1035 data points starting end ending on the earlier mentioned date. Number of days between 1/7/2014 abd 30/4/107 are 1035. On executing the code I get 1093 days, from your as well as my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ts` doesn't allow input for `start` and `end` in this form. Either a single number or a vector of two integers is allowed. In second case it's year and day number, starting from 1st January.

With the help of `lubridate` you can use the following. [`decimal_date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.0/topics/decimal_date) will convert the date to proper integer, suitable for `ts`.

```
library(lubridate)    
series <- ts(data1, start=decimal_date(as.Date("2014-07-01")), end=decimal_date(as.Date("2017-04-30") + 1), frequency = 365)

    > length(series)
    [1] 1035
```

Comment: Can you also tell me if I have to read this for weekly forecasting, what would I have to set my frequency to?